# How do I bind to a table <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

When someone **double clicks** on the entire row, I want an alert.
How do I bind a double click to an entire row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...

```
$('#table_id tr').dblclick(function(){
  alert('Hello');
});
```

**Note:** Using [JQuery](http://jquery.com) here, see more info about **[dblclick here](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)**.

Comment: @Alex - Please note that you must download/link to the jQuery framework for this function to work.  @Sarfraz - he didn't mention jQuery in his tags, was not sure if he would recognize the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Well, without jQuery I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'); // you do mean table rows, right?
var length = rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    rows[i].ondblclick = function(){alert('foo');};
}
```